# symfony2 twig render form 'choice' as list

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

How can I (in symfony2 twig) render the form control 'choice' (expanded, checkboxes) as list ('li's, or just with a 'br' inbetwwen each option) and not have all options appear on one line?

I guess I could bach a jQuery together, but isn't there a more native way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the appropriate theme block. There is a great description in the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html) how to do that.